ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.distributed._functional_collectives'
I'm trying to run databricks/dolly-v2-12b usage code in collab.
When I try their code:
%pip install "accelerate>=0.16.0,<1" "transformers[torch]>=4.28.1,<5" "torch>=1.13.1,<2"
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist
#import torch.distributed._functional_collectives as funcol
from transformers import pipeline

It complains
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.distributed._functional_collectives'

I looked around and found that maybe I needed
import torch.distributed._functional_collectives as funcol

but it says it does not exist.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.distributed._functional_collectives'

I tried to manually seach for this in the suggestions when I type it and it does not show up. I looked online and I cannot find how to import this correctly.
Am I missing another import to import distributed._functional_collectives? What am I missing?

Did you try pip install --upgrade torch torchvision ?
It worked for me.
